# I am trying to copy the data of one array to another array

Tags: assembly

The codes below is my attempt to copy contents from one array to another. But for some reason it is not working. Can someone help me with this?

```
;copy frequency array to calculation array
lea dx,frequency
lea ax,array
mov cx,512 

address:
mov bx, dx
mov ax, bx
inc dx
inc ax
loop address
```

Comment: Adding more detail would help this question. 1) What behavior are you currently seeing? You said it doesn't work, but why not? 2) The registers tell us this is Intel Architecture, but telling us if it's 32- or 64-bit would help. 3) Assembly is notoriously hard to follow - try to make it easier on your readers (potential helpers) by commenting your code. What is each line *supposed* to do?

Comment: This is for 32 bit. I have one array called frequency. It has some content in it. I want to copy it in array called array. By applying following codes it copies nothing on second array

Comment: `mov bx, dx` here you copied an address not the value stored at that address.  use [dx]  instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code fixed, explanation comes after :

```
;copy frequency array to calculation array
  lea  si, frequency      ;SI = POINTER TO FREQUENCY.
  lea  di, array          ;DI = POINTER TO ARRAY.
  mov  cx, 512            ;COUNTER.
address:
  mov  ax, [ si ]         ;GET TWO BYTES FROM FREQUENCY.
  mov  [ di ], ax         ;PUT TWO BYTES INTO ARRAY.
  add  si, 2              ;NEXT TWO BYTES IN FREQUENCY.
  add  di, 2              ;NEXT TWO BYTES IN ARRAY.
  sub  cx, 2              ;COUNTER-2.
  jnz  address            ;IF ( COUNTER != 0 ) REPEAT.
```

DX was changed by SI and AX by DI because DX and AX cannot be used as pointers, it is not allowed to do **[ ax ]** or **[ dx ]**. SI and DI are pointers by nature, their names mean "source index" and "destination index", so they can be used as **[ si ]** and **[ di ]**. It's extremely important to learn the difference between **SI** and **[SI]** : the first one is the address, the second is the content of the address.

SI, DI and CX are incremented/decremented by 2 because we are not moving bytes but words (two bytes). It's faster this way.

Finally, it's better to avoid using words like "address" because they might be reserved words.

Comment: Thank you so much Jose. I will be implementing it soon in my codes

Answer (score 2):

For moving strings, the [x86 string instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-5477/eoizn/index.html) can be a nice way to do it. The x86 string instructions use `ds:si` and `es:di` segment and offset register combinations to do byte or word moves between memory and the accumulator `ax`, or between two memory locations. Combined with the [`repnz`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_279.html) makes a compact solution:

```
lds   si, frequency     ; ds:si contains frequency pointer
les   di, array         ; es:di contains array pointer
mov   cx, 512           ; how many bytes to move
shr   cx, 1             ; how many words to move
cld                     ; clear direction bit to auto increment pointers on data moves
repnz movsw             ; move cx words from ds:si to es:di
```

`repnz` will repeat the next string instruction (in this case, `movsw`), decrementing `cx` after each execution, until `cx` becomes zero. A single `movsw` execution moves one word (2 bytes) from location pointed to by `ds:si` to location `es:di` and increments `si` and `di` each by 2 after the word move. The cleared direction bit from `cld` ensures that an increment is done on `si` and `di`, whereas if you set the direction bit (`std`), these pointer registers would be decremented.

I assumed that your 512 is a byte count. But if it's a word count to start with, then obviously you won't do the `shr cx,1` I show above.

The x86 string instructions support byte, word, and double word operations.